# accessing multimap value

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap

Suppose I create a multimap as

```
std::multimap<int, string> mm;
mm[1] = "name1";
mm[1] = "name2";

mm[2] = "name3"
mm[2] = "name4"
```

Here I am sure that each key has two value and ordering of value is important as name1 come first for mm[1] and name2 comes second for mm[1].

Can anyone please suggest the way to access mm values something like mm[1]{first value} without using counts here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
auto range = mm.equal_range(1);
std::for_each(range.first, range.second,
[](const std::pair<const int, std::string>& p)
{
   std::cout << p.second << std::endl;
});
```

Just a correction: `multimap` has no `operator []`. Use `insert` instead.

Comment: range.first and range.second come in random order or in same order in which it get inserted?

Comment: @dearvivekkumar as inserted i think. There is nothing about it in standard.

Comment: Thanks

But still I cannot relies on this.

I think I should create std::map<int, std::vector<string> >

Comment: I always try to use multimap but not happen to fit my situation

Comment: The order of elements with the same key is guaranteed to be the insertion order since C++11.

Comment: @Luc Touraille Thanks any idea about happens in C++03